# Reading a JSON file to edit

Tags: javascript

I was given a JSON file and told to read it to get a better understanding of how JavaScript programming works and edit this file to do what I need it to do. It's supposed to be a file to run some cleaning processes on client computers, so I just need to edit it so that they file will run all the processes I want it to run without having to send multiple commands to the computer through my RMM.

When I open the file however in Sublime Text 3 it looks like this. How do I get it to read as JavaScript programming language so I can edit it?

```
{"os":3,"procedure_type":1,"name":"Clear_PrinterSpool_DNSCache_EventLogs","description":"","version":"2.0","payload":"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","payloadChecksum":"d80877609ce0b19f6dcbe3c35d57cd03"}
```

Comment: This is perfectly valid JSON, you just need to find a plugin to format it for you so it's easier to read. Something like https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a backend call, the URL being pointed to the location of this JSON file.

In the result of that backend call, you will get the contents of the JSON file.